# UITableViewController with static cells: invisible cells when keyboard shows

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using a UITableViewController with static cells, as a user details form. Everything works, until I tap in one of the cells's text field, the keyboard (or custom inputView) shows up, and you scroll the table down. Cells are then not shown, instead a blank space is shown. Scrolling up and back down then correctly shows them.

If I scroll the tableview down until the "geboortedatum" field shows up,

[image]

and press on that textfield, a custom inputView with a date picker shows up:

[image]

Now, if I scroll the tableview down, the next rows show up blank:

[image]

Two rows are supposed to show up there, like this:

[image]

It's not related to the inputView with the date picker, the same happens when the plain old keyboard shows up and you scroll the table down.

I have not overridden any of the tableview delegate or datasource methods apart from showing custom headers (but the problem is the same when I remove that), and am not using UITableViewCell subclasses, just static cells in a storyboard. It seems like an iOS bug to me, but is there any way to work around this?

Comment: kevin, As I understood when you scroll the table view, your input value of textfield become a blank. Means input is missing from the textfield. Pls confirm it

Comment: can you add a normal image where those two rows actullay shows up ?

Comment: I've added a sceenshot of 2 two rows, when they are not hidden.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the cause and the solution. The problem is that these last 2 cells don't actually fit in the storyboard design:

[image]

They are there of course, just not visible by default. If I change the storyboard to freeform with a custom height to make it all fit, like this:

[image]

Then the problem doesn't show up anymore. The cells are not hidden anymore on scroll, as before. Very strange.